# Would it be possible to disable flycheck selected region on mark?

Tags: flycheck, region, customize-face

When I selected a region `Ctrl-space` up-arrow key, `flycheck` errors' font color are remain as it is.

Example, flycheck error makes fore-color bold orange:
[image]

Would it be possible to disable `flychecks` when a region is highlighted? Since highlight color is yellow, its difficult to read orange colored flycheck errors.

Comment: Alternatively, you might just want to change the background or face color.

Comment: Consider setting the overlay `priority` property of the flycheck error **lower than** the region overlay `priority` property, by redefining the function `flycheck-redefine-standard-error-levels`:  https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/blob/21d52264aa80bfa4ede94c59e37a20fb6d033b0c/flycheck.el#L4384  The region overlay `priority` property is `'(nil . 100)` -- see the variable `redisplay-highlight-region-function` within `simple.el`.   Inasmuch as I do not use flycheck, I am unable to test a potential solution and/or write-up an answer.

Comment: @Drew I tried multiple colors but if it different color that white all are difficult to read on top of yellow highlight :(

Comment: @lawlist Should I remove `(setf (get 'flycheck-warning-overlay 'priority) 100)` line?

Comment: The line of code that was linked in the second comment above was `(setf (get 'flycheck-error-overlay 'priority) 110)`, which was chosen because the question stated the face is for flycheck errors (rather than warnings).  You could try pasting the entire function to a scratch buffer, reduce `110` to something like `90`, evaluate the scratch buffer so that `flycheck-redefine-standard-error-levels` gets redefined, and then open up a new buffer and start flycheck and see if that works any better for you.  If the face is a warning face, then try modifying that line in a similar manner.

Comment: I have tried changing `setf (get 'flycheck-error-overlay 'priority) 110)` on its original path : `flycheck.el /home/alper/.emacs.d/elpa/flycheck-20210708.1337/` but changes does not affect anything :(

Comment: Sorry that my suggestion did not work.  Now that I think about it some more, the default region setting only affects the background, not the foreground.

Comment: Can't you change the background color of the face used in the overlay? It should be possible for you to change any colors - for face foreground or background, for text properties or overlay properties.

Comment: @Drew `background color` , do you mean the highlight color as yellow into something else?

Comment: I guess so. You tell me. A background color is typically for a frame (as frame parameter `background-color`) or a face, as attribute `background`. If for a face, it can be used as a text property (on a character) or as an overlay property (on a buffer position). If it's for a face, just customize the face. If it's for a frame then set that frame parameter.

Comment: I get used to use `background-color` as yellow for highlighting. My best option is to change color for flycheck-errors, since as I understand its difficult to disable their color when the region is highlighted